# Jsoup - Missing content

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I'm executing the following code with JSoup

```
Document parse = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/movies?near=<MyCity>&sort=1&start=0")
                       .followRedirects(true)
                       .ignoreContentType(true)
                       .timeout(12000)
                       .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                       .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                       .execute()
                       .parse();
Elements elements = parse.select(".movie_results .movie");
```

but when I inspect `elements`, it clearly miss a lot of content. I'm trying to get movie title and description from the page above.

What am I missing? Can this be related to missing header parameters, cookies?
Is there any other lib that could solve the problem?

I culd reproduce the same problem by executing:

```
curl http://www.google.com/movies?near=<MyCity>&sort=1&start=0 > page.html
```

**ProTip**

Just highlighting one of the comments: [try.jsoup.org](http://try.jsoup.org) is a good place to start using Jsoup. It helps you to parse the html in a very clean way.

Please, +1 if you liked the tip and saved your day :D

Comment: try it @ http://try.jsoup.org/. i see a lot of java script also

Comment: If you could reproduce the same problem just downloading the target, then it means that the information you want is just not there (is JSoup supposed to execute javascript to get the final html/css a person would see in a 'normal' browser?). Review the documentation for the API you're trying to use (i.e. google movies).

Comment: just posted the answer. +1 for your effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation using Google Chrome Dev Tools, I figured out that some header info was missing. The final code is similar to this one:

```
Jsoup.connect(url)
  .followRedirects(true)
  .ignoreContentType(true)
  .timeout(12000) // optional
  .header("Accept-Language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8") // missing
  .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch") // missing
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36") // missing
  .referrer("http://www.google.com") // optional
  .execute()
  .parse();
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I have done same as above but it is not loading full HTML page, it is giving half of the page. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try maxBodySize(0). Default maxBodysize is 2MB, so setting the maxBodySize to 0 willallows files of unlimited size.

```
     Jsoup.connect("your url").maxBodySize(0).followRedirects(true);
```